# How to get multiple selected values from select box in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a html form which have a select list box from which you can select multiple values because its multiple property is set to **multiple**. Consider form method is get method. The html code for form is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="display.jsp">
  <table width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><label>Multiple Selection </label>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><select name="select2" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
        <option value="11">eleven</option>
        <option value="12">twelve</option>
        <option value="13">thirette</option>
        <option value="14">fourteen</option>
        <option value="15">fifteen</option>
        <option value="16">sixteen</option>
        <option value="17">seventeen</option>
        <option value="18">eighteen</option>
        <option value="19">nineteen</option>
        <option value="20">twenty</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the selected values in select list box on display.jsp page. So how the selected values are accessed on display.jsp page.

Comment: @skaffman - I tagged `servlets`, because the retrieval of request parameters is done via the servlet API

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`request.getParameterValues("select2")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) returns an array of all submitted values.

Comment: Sir, link is not valid.

Answer (score 7):

Something along the lines of (using JSTL):

```
<p>Selected Values:
<ul>
  <c:forEach items="${paramValues['select2']}" var="selectedValue">
    <li><c:out value="${selectedValue}" /></li>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>
</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since I don't find a simple answer just adding more this will be JSP page. save this content to a jsp file once you run you can see the values of the selected displayed.

Update: save the file as test.jsp and run it on any web/app server

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<% String[] a = request.getParameterValues("multiple");
if(a!=null)
{
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
//out.println(Integer.parseInt(a[i])); //If integer
out.println(a[i]);
}}
%>
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.jsp" method="get">
<select name="multiple" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem overkill but Spring Forms handles this elegantly. That is of course if you are already using Spring MVC and you want to take advantage of the Spring Forms feature.

```
// jsp form
    <form:select path="friendlyNumber" items="${friendlyNumberItems}" />

    // the command class
    public class NumberCmd {
      private String[] friendlyNumber;
    }

    // in your Spring MVC controller submit method
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String manageOrders(@ModelAttribute("nbrCmd") NumberCmd nbrCmd){

       String[] selectedNumbers = nbrCmd.getFriendlyNumber();

    }
```