# How to get the values of a select multiple?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Generally we can get in the controller the posted values of the fields from JSP like this :

```
@Controller
public class someClass {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView someMethodName(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {

            // field name is got from param.getKey() , field value is got from param.getValue()

        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/someOtherUrl");

    }

}
```

The problem occurs if a field is a select element which is multiple. So how to get the values selected from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: [How to get multiple selected values from select box in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407945/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-from-select-box-in-jsp) has the right answer. Use a mapping of `List<String>` to obtain your results.

I'll leave this here, because this is right as well ;-)
Don't iterate over entries, but use the keySet. Those won't be duplicate by design.

i.e.:

```
for (String key: params.keySet()) {
    // field name key, field value is params.get(key)
}
```

Comment: I always got just one value even if I select more than one options ! NB : I tested with the `name` attribute of the select element with and without the `[ ]`

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407945/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-from-select-box-in-jsp I would try to use a Map<String> or a List<String> instead of Map<String,String>

Comment: you should change your answer because your last comment mentionning the link is the right answer :)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :-)