# Are there similar tags like <form:select> and <form:option> tags in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot, jsp-tags

is there something similar to tags  and  tags in spring boot? I should make a following page:
[image]

I was considering to use SimpleFormController but it exists in Spring MVC. In my current project we are using spring boot + jsp (Now I am considering thymleaf, but I prefer to use jsp, we have already used it). May be you can give me some useful advice, in any way I will appreciate you for help.

Comment: I think that I have just found one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407945/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-from-select-box-in-jsp

Comment: Prefer Thymeleaf over JSP when using Spring Boot. JSP with Spring Boot (or rather embedded containers) have severe limitations. Next to that it is a technology that more or less has stalled. Spring Boot uses Spring MVC so what ever you can do with Spring MVC you can do with Spring Boot. Spring Boot is additional configuration and ease of use for Spring based applications.

Comment: please write this text as answer and I will vote for it.